# What is the proper way to create IMAP subfolders using imapclient for Python?

Tags: python, imap, dovecot, imapclient

I have code that looks something like this

```
import imapclient

archive_folder = "Archive"

aggregate_reports_folder = "{0}/Aggregate".format(archive_folder)
forensic_reports_folder = "{0}/Forensic".format(archive_folder)

server = imapclient.IMAPClient("example.com", use_uid=True)
server.login("user", "foobar")

if not server.folder_exists(archive_folder):
    server.create_folder(archive_folder)
if not server.folder_exists(aggregate_reports_folder):
    server.create_folder(aggregate_reports_folder)
if not server.folder_exists(forensic_reports_folder):
    server.create_folder(forensic_reports_folder)
```

It works fine on Office 365/Exchange, but not dovecot. On dovecot it causes an error:

> Error: create failed: [CANNOT] Invalid mailbox name: Name must not have '/' characters

I tried removing the `/subfolder` part of the folder name, and running `select_folder(archive_folder)` first, but that just creates folders at the same level as Archive. Yet, Thunderbird can create subfolders without a problem.

How can I create IMAP subfolders using imapclient, in a way that works with all IMAP servers? Also, How do I move mail to those subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the dovecot [mailing list](http://dovecot.dovecot.narkive.com/cSQ9ndzQ/maildir-folder-separator).

> Currently Dovecot supports only Maildir++ directory layout, which
>   specifies that '.' character is used as the separator in the filesystem.

So when building subfolder paths, use `.` as the separator, not `/`.

Comment: The output of the list command includes the mailbox separator character.  I don't know if imapclient gives you access to this information easily.

Comment: @Max Yes, the `list_folders()`/`list_subfolders()` methods include the separator as second element in each entry.